# JDBC + statement.setEscapeProcessing(false)

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Just want to know the exact effects of statement.setEscapeProcessing(false)  as anywhere in documentation i am not finding proper explaination  here are my questions

1) statement.setEscapeProcessing(false) will not any effects if we dont have escape clause in query . is this correct ?

2) If first one is correct why query modification happens even if i dont use any escape clause in my query but table name contains some special caharcter like ?  and also statement.setEscapeProcessing(true) which is default. i tested this out here ? gets replaced with ':1' witout the quotes

sample query - SELECT * FROM CLIENT.\"abc?table\" where rownum=1

when i set statement.setEscapeProcessing(false) and run the above query it works i.e no    replacement happens

3) if statement.setEscapeProcessing(true) does escape for the whole query then whta is the exact difference between escape processing true and escaping the values using preparedStatement

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [JDBC 4.0 specifications document](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html), section 13.4 to understand more about setEscapeProcessing() method.